# Permutation question. $qpq^{-1}$, $q,p,r,s \in S_{8}$.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $p,r,s,q \in S_{8}$ be the permutation given by the following products of cycles:
$$p=(1,4,3,8,2)(1,2)(1,5)$$
$$q=(1,2,3)(4,5,6,8)$$
$$r=(1,2,3,8,7,4,3)(5,6)$$
$$s=(1,3,4)(2,3,5,7)(1,8,4,6)$$

Compute $qpq^{-1}$ and $r^{-2}sr^{2}.$

thanks for your help.

I want to write the following permutations like :

$p=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\4&1&8&3&?&?&?&2\end{pmatrix}$

$q=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\2&3&1&5&6&8&7&4\end{pmatrix}$

$r=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 2&3&8&3&6&5&4&7\end{pmatrix}$

$s=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 3&?&4&1&?&?&?&?\end{pmatrix}$

can you help me plese to fill the $?$ mark. Is there another method to compute $qpq^{-1}$?

thanks:)

Comment: How did you fill in the numbers that are not question marks?

Comment: If $f=(a_1 , a_2 ,...,a_r)$ (cyle notation) then 
$gfg^{-1} = (g(a_1) , g(a_2) ,... ,g(a_r))$ (see
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766083))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume right to left associativity, as is usually the case. Note that 
$$(\alpha \beta)^{-1} = {\beta}^{-1} {\alpha}^{-1}, \text{ and}$$
$$ (a_1 a_2 \dots a_n)^{-1} = (a_1 a_n \dots a_2).$$
These are standard facts, and easily shown if you like to. Hence,
$$qpq^{-1} = (1 2 3)(4 5 6 8)(1 4 3 8 2)(1 2)(1 5)(4 8 6 5)(1 3 2).$$
I know no smart way to do this, and write the changes down one cycle at a time, right to left. For instance, after the first step, $(1 3 2)$, you get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 2&3&1&4&5&6&7&8\end{pmatrix}.$$
After the next step, $(4 8 6 5)$, you get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 2&3&1&5&6&8&7&4\end{pmatrix}.$$
If you keep going with the remaining cycles, you get
$$qpq^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 5&6&4&3&2&8&7&1\end{pmatrix},$$
if I didn't mess a step up. You read off the resulting permutation, written as cycles:
$$qpq^{-1} = (15268)(34).$$
You calculate $r^{-2}sr^2$ similarly. It's grindwork mostly.

*Edit*: took it temporarily down to correct some typos.

*Edit 2* - write $p$ (per comment below):

You apply the $3$ cycles of $p = (14382)(12)(15)$ one step at a time. Applying $(15)$ first, you get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 5&2&3&4&1&6&7&8\end{pmatrix}.$$
Applying $(12)$ next, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 2&5&3&4&1&6&7&8\end{pmatrix}.$$
Finally applying the last cycle $(14382)$, we get
$$p = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 5&8&4&2&1&6&7&3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: please tell me, how can I write $p$ with two lines ? thanks

Comment: @Iuli: I will add this as a second edit directly into the answer, step by step. But it's a little typework, so please hold on.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot :-)

Comment: why here, is not same http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+4+3+8+2%29%281+2%29%281+5%29permutation ?

Comment: I don't know, but that can't be right. Follow just the trail of the 5: after step 1, is in position 1; after step 2, it is in position 2; after step 3, it is in position 1 again. So 5 ends at position 1 (look at the cycles, right to left). But Wolfram has a 4 in position 1. 4 gets only moved in the final cycle, to whatever was in 3; but 3 is not moved in (12)(15), so it goes to 3. Can't be right.

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick way to compute both of your permutations, and it is by using this fact:

Suppose $\tau, \sigma \in S_n$ and in cycle notation, $\sigma = (a_1, a_2, \cdots a_p) (b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_q) \cdots (z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_l)$ say. Then $$ \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1), \tau(a_2), \cdots \tau(a_p)) (\tau(b_1), \tau(b_2), \cdots, \tau(b_q)) \cdots (\tau(z_1), \tau(z_2), \cdots, \tau(z_l))$$

That is, to conjugate by $\tau$, replace the elements in the cycles of $\sigma$ by their images under $\tau.$ Exercise: Prove this.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a quicker way to do this.  As an exercise, prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Suppose that $\alpha$ is an arbitrary permutation and $\beta$ is an $n$-cycle, written $\beta=(\beta_1\hspace{5pt} \beta_2 \hspace{5pt}\ldots \hspace{5pt}\beta_n)$.  Then $$\alpha^{-1}\beta \alpha=(\alpha(\beta_1)\hspace{5pt}\alpha(\beta_2)\hspace{5pt}\ldots \hspace{5pt}\alpha(\beta_n)).$$  In other words, $\alpha^{-1}\beta\alpha$ is the $n$-cycle with $\alpha$ applied to its letters.

Since any permutation can be decomposed into the product of disjoint cycles, say $\gamma=a_1a_2\ldots a_k$ where $a_i$ are disjoint cycles, we can write $$\alpha^{-1}\gamma\alpha=\alpha^{-1}a_1a_2\ldots a_k\alpha=(\alpha^{-1}a_1\alpha)(\alpha^{-1}a_2\alpha)(\alpha^{-1}\ldots \alpha )(\alpha^{-1}a_k\alpha)$$
so by induction the lemma shows that $\alpha^{-1}\gamma\alpha$ is the permutation with the same cycle structure as $\gamma$ with $\alpha$ applied to the letters in each of its disjoint cycles.

Now, $p$ in disjoint cycles is just $p=(1,4,3,8,5)$ and $s$ in disjoint cycles is just $s=(1,5,7,2,3,6)(4,8)$.

So, we apply $q$ to the letters in $p$ and obtain $q^{-1}pq=(1,4,6,2,5)$, then $r^2$ to the letters in each disjoint cycle of $s$ and obtain $r^{-2}sr^2=(1,8,7,6,3,5)(2,4)$.

I'll leave it to you to put these back into permutation notation (which is easy, since the cycles are disjoint!)

Answer (score 1):

If you write all right then
$$
p= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\4&1&8&3&5&6&7&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\2&1&3&4&5&6&7&8
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\5&2&3&4&1&6&7&8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so on (sorry, I write badly the formula). So you have first to calculate $p,q,r,s$.

Comment: why? can you explicate please ?

Comment: @Iuli *explain. $(1,4,3,8,2)=(1,4,3,8,2)(5)(6)(7)$. The others are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is composing the permutation from left to right rather than right to left. You can do these compositions of permutations as follows- Using $(14382)(12)(15)$ and going from left to right the first row below reads $1$ goes to $4$ in the first cycle. Since there is no $4$ in the second cycle write $4$ goes to $4$ and no $4$ in the third cycle write $4$ goes to $5$. This summarizes to $1$ goes to $4$ at the end.  Repeat this for $2$ through $8$ then write the multiplication based on the last two columns.

$$1\to 4\    4\to4\ 4\to4\  1\to 4$$
$$2\to 1\    1\to2\ 2\to2\  2\to 2$$
$$3\to 8\    8\to8\ 8\to8\  3\to 8$$
$$4\to 3\    3\to3\ 3\to3\  4\to 3$$
$$5\to 5\    5\to5\ 5\to1\  5\to 1$$
$$6\to 6\    6\to6\ 6\to6\  6\to 6$$
$$7\to 7\    7\to7\ 7\to7\  7\to 7$$
$$8\to 2\    2\to1\ 1\to5\  8\to 5$$

Summarizing the last two columns we have $(14385)$ in cycle notation. This also can be written as 
p=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\4&2&8&3&1&6&7&5\end{pmatrix}

In words $1$ goes to $4$; $4$ goes to $3$; $3$ goes to $8$; $8$ goes to $5$; and $5$ goes back to $1$. $2$, $6$ and $7$ are fixed.

If you compose the same permutations right to left you get

$$1\to 5\    5\to5\ 5\to5\  1\to 5$$
$$2\to 2\    2\to1\ 1\to4\  2\to 4$$
$$3\to 3\    3\to3\ 3\to8\  3\to 8$$
$$4\to 4\    4\to4\ 4\to3\  4\to 3$$
$$5\to 1\    1\to2\ 2\to1\  5\to 1$$
$$6\to 6\    6\to6\ 6\to6\  6\to 6$$
$$7\to 7\    7\to7\ 7\to7\  7\to 7$$
$$8\to 8\    8\to8\ 8\to2\  8\to 2$$

Summarizing the last two columns we have $(15)(2438)$ in cycle notation. This also can be written as 
p=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\5&4&8&3&1&6&7&2\end{pmatrix}

In words $1$ goes to $5$; $5$ goes to back to $1$; $2$ goes to $4$; $4$ goes to $3$; and $3$ goes to $8$ and $8$ goes back to $2$.   $6$ and $7$ are fixed. I always thought permutations were supposed to composed right to left but I have seen it both ways which makes it confusing.

Now let's fill in the blanks for $s= (134)(2357)(1846)$going from left to right and coming up with the same disjoint cycles as Alexander Gruber in his answer.

$$1\to 3\    3\to5\ 5\to5\  1\to 5$$
$$2\to 2\    2\to3\ 3\to3\  2\to 3$$
$$3\to 4\    4\to4\ 4\to6\  3\to 6$$
$$4\to 1\    1\to1\ 1\to8\  4\to 8$$
$$5\to 5\    5\to7\ 7\to7\  5\to 7$$
$$6\to 6\    6\to6\ 6\to1\  6\to 1$$
$$7\to 7\    7\to2\ 2\to2\  7\to 2$$
$$8\to 8\    8\to8\ 8\to4\  8\to 4$$

Summarizing the last two columns we have $(157236)(48)$ in cycle notation. This also can be written as 
s=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\5&3&6&8&7&1&2&4\end{pmatrix}

In words $1$ goes to $5$; $5$ goes to $7$; $7$ goes to $2$; $2$ goes to $3$; $3$ goes to $6$ and $6$ goes to $1$ which completes the cycle. Then $4$ goes to $8$ and $8$ goes to $4$ which completes that cycle.