# Proof "correctness" : Cycle structure of conjugate permutations

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, permutations

My Algebra lecturer is a very strict about proofs(w.r.t Completeness , correctness and format ) more so than I have encountered in the past or any of my lecturers of the courses I am take concurrent. I do appreciate this as Mathematics along with other scientific disciplines are found on being as precise as possible. It does make it rather difficult to judge  what constitutes a proof, Which brings me onto my main topic

**The Question**:
Suppose $f \in S_n$ and consists of a single cycle $( a_1 , a_2 ,...,a_r).$ Let $g\in S_n$ and show that  $gfg^{-1} = (g(a_1) , g(a_2) ,... ,g(a_r)) $ and furthermore show that $f$ and $gfg^{-1}$ has the same disjoint cycle structure

**My Proposed Proof**:

Suppose  $a_i \in \{a_1, a_2,...,a_r\}$

Let  $h = gfg^{-1}$.  Since $f(a_i) = a_{i+1}$

then

$$ h(g(a_i) = gfg^{-1} g(a_i)$$
$$ = g(f(a_i)) = g(a_{i+1})$$

So $gfg^{-1} $ has a cycle $(g(a_1) , g(a_2) ,... ,g(a_r)) $

otherwise $a_i \in \{ a_{r+1} ,.., a_n\}$

Since  $f(a_i) =a_i$

then
 $$ h(g(a_i) = gfg^{-1} g(a_i)$$
$$ = g(f(a_i)) = g(a_{i})$$

So  $f$ and $gfg^{-1}$ has the same disjoint cycle structure

If this proof correct, and if so any suggestions/comments about additions and changes that should be made in order to make the proof as complete , rigorous and properly formatted.

Comment: Do you still need to show that $f$ and $gfg^{-1}$ has the same disjoint cycle structure?

Comment: @Thomas Have I not done that? Since they have a single cycle of length r.

Comment: I don't think you have made it clear why $f$ and $gfg^{-1}$ when written as products of disjoint cycles have the "same structure".

Comment: @Thomas How would I make that more explicit

Comment: I think that since the problem explicitly says: "Furthermore show that ..." that usually means that you have to say more than the conclusion. You basically have all you need, and I personally don't think that you need to do more. But again, can you some how make it über explicit?

Comment: I think what Thomas is getting at is that you need a sentence or two explain how this argument can be applied (very easily) to permutations of any cycle type. Right now you've shown it for the permutations which are $r$-cycles.

Comment: @JMag Would It be sufficient to  because they both have disjoint cycle of the same length one of length r and $(n-r-1) of length 1 they have the same structure?

Comment: Let me be a bit more concrete. You have already proved this result for $r$-cycles, for any given $r$. Now suppose I have $(1,2,3)(4,5,6,7)(8)(9)$. How does your argument show that $g(1,2,3)(4,5,6,7)(8)(9)g^{-1}$ does not change the cycle structure?

Comment: @JMag It is because $g(1,2,3)(4,5,6,7)(8)(9)g^{-1}$ would also have a 3-cycle, 4-cycle and 2 1-cycles?

Comment: That's the conclusion you're trying to make. Here's how you make it $g(1,2,3)(4,5,6,7)(8)(9)g^{-1} = g(1,2,3,4)g^{-1}g(4,5,6,7)g^{-1}g(8)g^{-1}g(9)g^{-1}$. You result applies to each of the disjoint cycles. Therefore the cycle structure of any permutation $f\in S_n$ will be unchanged by conjugation.

Comment: @JMag $g(a_1,...,a_r)(a_{r+1},a_{r+2})g^{-1} = g(a_1,...,a_r)g^{-1} g (a_{r+1},a_{r+2}) g^{-1}$  true in all cases?

Comment: @JMag How would I express this?