# Interesting property of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let's fix a permutation
$$\sigma = (a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_r)(b_1, b_2, \ldots,b_m).$$
I would like to show that
$$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1), \tau(a_2), \ldots, \tau(a_r))(\tau(b_1), \tau(b_2), \ldots, \tau(b_m)).$$
This property is quite interesting form me and I don't know to visualize it for small $r$ and $m$. I would appreciate a sketch of the proof.

Comment: Why don't you express this "interesting property" for the simpler case $\sigma = (a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_r)$ and $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1), \tau(a_2), \ldots, \tau(a_r))$ ? See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766083 where this simpler question is adressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the definition of the cycle notation. $(a_1,...,a_r)(b_1,...,b_m)$ means $a_1$ is permuted to $a_2$, $a_2$ is permuted to $a_3$, etc.

So if you want to show $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau(a_1),...,\tau(a_r))(\tau(b_1),...,\tau(b_r))$ all you need to do is show $\tau(a_1)$ is permuted to $\tau(a_2)$ by $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$, $\tau(a_2)$ is permuted to $\tau(a_3)$ by $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$, etc. Do you see why this holds?

One more tip: If you permute $a$ by $\sigma$, you get $\sigma(a)$. If you permute $\tau(a)$ by $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$, you get $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\tau(a)$. So what happens when you permute $\tau(a_1)$ using $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$? Remember, $\tau^{-1}\tau$ just does nothing (by definition of inverse).

Comment: Not really. I would appreciate one more tip.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!